# Find multiple id parameter in id list

Tags: sql, arrays, list, select

Id,s to find string : '1,5,6'

```
@idstofind = '1,5,6'
```

From id table:

```
idtable
-------
10
20
1
5
9
6
10
```

And:

```
Result
------
1
5
6
```

I need something like this:

```
Select * from dbo.splitstring(@idstofind) as itf in (select * from idtable)
```

Comment: The best answer would be to use Table Valued Parameters instead of passing a string. If your client library doesn't support it then have a look at http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: posting search result for multiple cpu type in cpu id table from a web page.
so each time i'll delete table and revalued for each request?
i couldnt find anything for this issue.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb510489.aspx for Table Valued Parameters. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx as an example of using them from C#

Comment: Should we assume a typo in `idtable` since it does not contain "6" in your sample data?

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
Select id 
  from idtable
 where id in (@idstofind)
```